# Jenkins console output: What does A and AU mean?

Tags: jenkins

I was wondering, what does `A` and `AU` mean in Jenkins? I am watching my stuff run through the console at the moment, just wondering. Doesn't seem like there is any info at all on google about this. (Then again, it might just not like this short of a search term)

This is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's **output from your SCM** checkout step -- you're using Subversion.

The lines have the same meaning as the output of a svn checkout command ("A" means "added", "U" means "updated"). See the [Subversion docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) for a full description of all flags.